# Google Assistant SDKを実行できません

Tags: python, python3, raspberry-pi, python-venv

Google Assistant SDK の公式ドキュメントの [Run the Sample Code](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/service/python/embed/run-sample) を実行すると以下のエラーが発生します。
何か知っている方がいましたら教えてくださるとうれしいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/futa/env/bin/googlesamples-assistant-pushtotalk", line 5, in <module>
    from googlesamples.assistant.grpc.pushtotalk import main
  File "/home/futa/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/googlesamples/assistant/grpc/pushtotalk.py", line 27, in <module>
    from google.assistant.embedded.v1alpha1 import embedded_assistant_pb2
  File "/home/futa/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/assistant/embedded/v1alpha1/embedded_assistant_pb2.py", line 36, in <module>
    _descriptor.EnumValueDescriptor(
  File "/home/futa/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/protobuf/descriptor.py", line 755, in __new__
    _message.Message._CheckCalledFromGeneratedFile()
TypeError: Descriptors cannot not be created directly.
If this call came from a _pb2.py file, your generated code is out of date and must be regenerated with protoc >= 3.19.0.
If you cannot immediately regenerate your protos, some other possible workarounds are:
 1. Downgrade the protobuf package to 3.20.x or lower.
 2. Set PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_PYTHON_IMPLEMENTATION=python (but this will use pure-Python parsing and will be much slower).

More information: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/news/2022-05-06#python-updates
```

Comment: エラーメッセージ中にどう対応すべきかは書かれているように見えますが、(翻訳にかけてでも) 読みましたか？

Comment: はい一応確認はしました

Comment: いまいちよくわからなかったので質問させていただきました

Comment: 説明不足だと思うのでどのように書き直せばいいでしょうか